# How can I include the index of a clicked image in my img tag?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic. I am on Ionic Framework version 5.4.16, and I am on Windows 10.

The following code lists all of my images from Firebase. When I click on any of the images, I would like to direct that to my "order" page and show only that particular image. This code is from my gallery.html file.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let booking of Bookings" class="user-list">
    <div class="card"><h2><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image1}} [routerLink]="['/order']"></ion-img></h2>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

This code is from my order.html file.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let booking of Bookings; index as indexOfelement;" class="user-list" >
    <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
        <div class="card"><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image1}}></ion-img>                </div>
        <div class="card"><h2><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image2}}></ion-img></h2></div>
        <div class="card"><h2><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image3}}></ion-img></h2></div>
    </div>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"An item is considered "clickable" if it has an href or button property set", you can check more here at this documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item,

you can add click button to your element :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let booking of Bookings; index as indexOfelement;" class="user-list" >
    <div class="scrolling-wrapper" (click)="openUser(item)">
        <div class="card"><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image1}}></ion-img>                </div>
        <div class="card"><h2><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image2}}></ion-img></h2></div>
        <div class="card"><h2><ion-img id="img" width="250" height="160" src={{booking.image3}}></ion-img></h2></div>
    </div>
```